# javascript validation phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

alright, whats wrong with my script, JShint is throwing three lines of red code saying i have issues in my variable and my if/else statement. I am trying to validate if the phone number is a valid USA phone format

```
    $( "#phone" ).focusout(function telephone() {
    if( this.value === "" || this.value === null ) {
        $( "#error_messages" ).text("");
        return false;
    } else {
        var re = \d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4};
        if(re.test(document.getElementById("phone").value)) {
            $( "#error_messages" ).text("");
            return true;
        } else {
            $( "#error_messages" ).text("Phone Number* not a valid format xxx-xxx-xxxx");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: regex need to be defined inside `/regex/`. change it to `/\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}/`

Comment: And what are those errors?

Comment: Also change, `re.test(document.getElementById("phone").value)` to `re.test($(this).val())`, since you are binding focusout on same element and using jquery as well.

Comment: rajesh answered it, works now thank you!!

Comment: @AronLilland Use `/^\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$/` regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need a name for closure function. Secondly you have not enclosed regex with `/..../`.

```
var re = /\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should try this.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#phone").change(function telephone() {      
      if (this.value === "" || this.value === null) {
        $("#error_messages").text("");
        return false;
      } else {        
        if (/\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}/.test($(this).val())) {
            $("#error_messages").text("");
            return true;
          } else {
            $("#error_messages").text("Phone Number* not a valid format xxx-xxx-xxxx");
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone" />
<span id="error_messages"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an expression tested on http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/# for numbers. change it to `/^\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$/` in your JS code and apply regex code within `/..../` in that tools

I applied

```
^\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$
```

It's ok with your numbers :
[image]